# Is there a way to transform these 2 arrays by using jq, into a set of objects, like in the example down below?

Tags: jq

Example json data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "place": "FM346",
      "id": [
        "7_day_A",
        "7_day_B",
        "7_day_C",
        "7_day_D"
      ],
      "values": [
        0,
        30,
        23,
        43
      ]
    },
    {
      "place": "LH210",
      "id": [
        "1_day_A",
        "1_day_B",
        "1_day_C",
        "1_day_D"
      ],
      "values": [
        4,
        45,
        100,
        9
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

what i need to transform it into:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "place": "FM346",
      "7_day_A": {
        "value": 0
      },
      "7_day_B": {
        "value": 30
      },
      "7_day_C": {
        "value": 23
      },
      "7_day_D": {
        "value": 43
      }
    },
    {
      "place": "LH210",
      "1_day_A": {
        "value": 4
      },
      "1_day_B": {
        "value": 45
      },
      "1_day_C": {
        "value": 100
      },
      "1_day_D": {
        "value": 9
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

i have tried this:

```
{
    data:[.data |.[]|
    {   
        place: (.place),
        (.id[]): 
        {
            value: (.values[])
        }
    }] 
}
```

(in jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/f4BBtN9gwmp)

and this:

```
{
    data:[.data |.[]|
    {   
        place: (.place),
        test:
        [{
            (.id[]): 
            {
            value: (.values[])
            }
        }]
    }] 
}
```

(in jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/pKIvQe1CzgX)

but they arent grouped in the way i wanted and it gives each value to each id, not the corresponding one.
I have been trying for some time now, but im new to jq and have no idea how to transform it this way, thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transpose` here, which can play a key role in converting the arrays to key/value pairs

```
.data[] |= {place} + 
   ([ .id, .values ] | transpose | map({(.[0]): { value: .[1] } }) | add)
```

The solution works by converting the array-of-arrays `[.id, .values]` by transposing them, i.e. converting

```json
[["7_day_A","7_day_B","7_day_C","7_day_D"],[0,30,23,43]]
[["1_day_A","1_day_B","1_day_C","1_day_D"],[4,45,100,9]]
```

to

```json
[["7_day_A",0],["7_day_B",30],["7_day_C",23],["7_day_D",43]]
[["1_day_A",4],["1_day_B",45],["1_day_C",100],["1_day_D",9]]
```

With the transformation done, we construct an object with key as the zeroth index element and value as an object comprising of the value of first index element, and combine the results together with `add`

Demo - [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/AdxDDFFUeN5)